# How do I change a QGIS buffer size?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to make buffers around points on a map in qgis. For some reason, when I try to make buffers, they take up a lot of space on the map.

I ensured that my CRS is the same as the map, which is WGS 84.

Does anyone know why the buffers are so large around each of my points?

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if you can change the units while creating the buffer. But with experimentation I found out that 1 metre is 0.00001 in Buffer Distance units. So if you want to create a buffer around your point of 40 metres, enter 0.0004 in Buffer distance.